# Bind GridView Column to List element at fixed index

Tags: c#, data-binding, gridview

I'm trying bind a GridView Column to a List element at a fixed index, but I get an exception when I execute `Grid.DataBind();`:

> Unable to find field or property named 'Misure[0].ID' from the
>   selected data source.

Custom Classes:

```
public partial class RowTabellaConcentrazioneGiornaliera
{
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public string DataString { get; set; }
    public List<MisuraConcentrazione> Misure { get; set; }

}

public partial class MisuraConcentrazione
{
    public double MediaOraTQ { get; set; }
    public double MediaOraNorm { get; set; }
    public double ID { get; set; }
    public string IVTQ { get; set; }
    public string IVN { get; set; }
    public string MeasureCod { get; set; }
    public string DescrizioneParametro { get; set; }
}
```

GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridDatiConcentrazione" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField  DataField="DataString" HeaderText="Ora" ItemStyle-Width="50px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Mehod:

```
    protected void SetTabellaSintesiConcentrazioniGiornaliere(BFStat.BFStat _BFStat1, GridView Grid)
    {
        //Carica Griglia di sintesi concentrazione
        List<RowTabellaConcentrazioneGiornaliera> y = _BFStat1.GetConcentrazioniOrarie();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (MisuraConcentrazione riga in y[0].Misure)
        {
            BoundField NewColonnaID = new BoundField();
            NewColonnaID.HeaderText = "Ind. Disp.";
            NewColonnaID.DataField = "Misure[" + i + "].ID";
            Grid.Columns.Add(NewColonnaID);

            BoundField NewColonnaValueTQ = new BoundField();
            NewColonnaValueTQ.HeaderText = "Valore TQ";
            NewColonnaValueTQ.DataField = "Misure[" + i + "].MediaOraTQ";
            Grid.Columns.Add(NewColonnaValueTQ);

            BoundField NewColonnaIVTQ = new BoundField();
            NewColonnaIVTQ.HeaderText = "Validità TQ";
            NewColonnaIVTQ.DataField = "Misure[" + i + "].IVTQ";
            Grid.Columns.Add(NewColonnaIVTQ);

            BoundField NewColonnaValueN = new BoundField();
            NewColonnaValueN.HeaderText = "Valore N";
            NewColonnaValueN.DataField = "Misure[" + i + "].MediaOraNorm";
            Grid.Columns.Add(NewColonnaValueN);

            BoundField NewColonnaIVN = new BoundField();
            NewColonnaIVN.HeaderText = "Validità N";
            NewColonnaIVN.DataField = "Misure[" + i + "].IVN";
            Grid.Columns.Add(NewColonnaIVN);

            i++;
        }

        Grid.DataSource = y;
        Grid.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: `DataField` should be a property name, so obviously "Misure[0].ID" won't work, but what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: In the List `Misure` I have a variable number of element. I want add to the grid five columns for each element and put in those columns data from the proprieties of that elements.

Comment: You don't to add columns for each item, but for the whole list. After you added columns you need to bind the list to the grid.

Comment: Yeah this is the "regular" method, but if you look at the grid declaration I have another column that is binded to a property of `RowTabellaConcentrazioneGiornaliera`. So I can not bind the entire `List<RowTabellaConcentrazioneGiornaliera> y` to the Grid.

Comment: If you have a list inside a list then you need two grids

Comment: Tks, tomorrow I'll try that.. I hoped in a easyer solution but it seems impossible.

Comment: Someone can post a little example here? I can't find anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I partially solved my problem using more grids and table.

I created a main  control and added columns via code. Inside that columns I put other GridViews. I choose  instead of a GridView becouse it's easier to work with it's column.

I had to elab my datasource splitting it in more lists but from now I'll choose another structure for pass my data from the calc methods to the visualization methods.

Thanks everybody for the help ;)

Comment: Could you include some code snippets to elaborate on how you accomplished this?